# how to use conditional operator in dataweave in Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave

Hi i am trying to write a conditional expression instead of using when in data weave. I am not getting how to achieve this.

I am trying to write something as mention below to filter condition with in the statement:

```html
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
 data: payload,
 paylo: (sizeOf payload) < 20 ? 90:0
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code would help you for  applying the condition

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    data: payload,
    paylo: 90 when sizeOf payload < 20 otherwise 0

}
```

The documentation should help you understand [sizeOf](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/dataweave#_size_of) and [conditional statements](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/dataweave#_when_otherwise)

Comment: i dont want to use when operator , i need conditional

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to use When operator ? Also can you add this to the question if that is one of the main constrain (Although I don't have see a need to it , personally)